# Aggregating the columns resulted by PIVOT function

Tags: sql, oracle, analytics

I use below query using PIVOT function:

```
SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT medicine_name, YEAR_OF_PURCHASE, profit_in_rupees FROM temp_1
         )
         PIVOT
            (AVG (NVL (profit_in_rupees, 0)) AS avg_profit
            FOR (year_of_purchase)
            IN ('2017' AS "2017", '2018' AS "2018"))
ORDER BY medicine_name;
```

and this is successfully giving me two required columns, `2017_AVG_PROFIT` and `2018_AVG_PROFIT`, now I have to add two more columns in the same query.

1) I want to add a column which can show me the difference between these two columns, means `2018_AVG_PROFIT` minus `2017_AVG_PROFIT`.
2) I also want to know that who less percentage of profit we have done in 2018 as compared to 2017 using the above column values.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT   medicine_name, 
         "2017_AVG_PROFIT", 
         "2018_AVG_PROFIT", 
         Nvl("2017_AVG_PROFIT", 0) - Nvl("2018_AVG_PROFIT", 0) AS "DIFF_AVG_PROFIT", 
         CASE "2017_AVG_PROFIT" 
                  WHEN 0 THEN NULL 
                  ELSE Cast(Nvl("2018_AVG_PROFIT", 0) AS DECIMAL(12,2)) / 
                    Cast("2017_AVG_PROFIT" AS DECIMAL(12,2))
         END AS "PERC_DIFF" 
FROM     ( 
                SELECT medicine_name, 
                       year_of_purchase, 
                       profit_in_rupees 
                FROM   temp_1 ) PIVOT (avg (nvl (profit_in_rupees, 0)) 
                                       AS avg_profit FOR (year_of_purchase) IN ('2017' AS "2017",
                                                                                                                '2018' AS "2018"))
ORDER BY medicine_name;
```

For this sample schema/data:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_1
(
  medicine_name varchar2(25), 
  year_of_purchase number(4),
  profit_in_rupees number(10)
);

INSERT INTO temp_1 (medicine_name, year_of_purchase, profit_in_rupees) VALUES ('m1', 2017, 100);
INSERT INTO temp_1 (medicine_name, year_of_purchase, profit_in_rupees) VALUES ('m2', 2017, 200);
INSERT INTO temp_1 (medicine_name, year_of_purchase, profit_in_rupees) VALUES ('m3', 2017, 300);
INSERT INTO temp_1 (medicine_name, year_of_purchase, profit_in_rupees) VALUES ('m1', 2018, 400);
INSERT INTO temp_1 (medicine_name, year_of_purchase, profit_in_rupees) VALUES ('m2', 2018, 100);
INSERT INTO temp_1 (medicine_name, year_of_purchase, profit_in_rupees) VALUES ('m3', 2018, 100);
```

It returns:

```
MEDICINE_NAME   2017_AVG_PROFIT  2018_AVG_PROFIT     DIFF_AVG_PROFIT     PERC_DIFF
m1              100              400                 -300                4
m2              200              100                 100                 0.5
m3              300              100                 200                 0.333
```

Comment: Thanks Max you nailed it.

Comment: Bro, can you please explain this part how did you just do that.  (CASE "2017_AVG_PROFIT" 
                  WHEN 0 THEN NULL 
                  ELSE Cast(Nvl("2018_AVG_PROFIT", 0) AS DECIMAL(12,2)) / 
                    Cast("2017_AVG_PROFIT" AS DECIMAL(12,2))
         END AS "PERC_DIFF")

Comment: You may use `ROUND` function in place of casting to decimal